# React SSR. Right place to invoke ReactDOM.hydrate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, server-side-rendering, react-dom

I have a CSR react application running on port `3000`. Now I need to create SSR app for this. I created a new server running on port `3003` and the server returns html template as expected. But the returned template is not a react app. react devtools not detecting and javascript event handlers are not working.
I know I need to hydrate the html template from server. but i don't know the right place to invoke `ReactDOM.hydrate()`. Should I invoke this in the server application?
Because i am accessing the port `3003` for SSR.